# PHP, CSV file to array, html values

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I'm using this code to read any CSV file to build an array so that i can use it later, the problem I have is that this particular CSV file has columns with html

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('docs/foo.csv'));
$headers = $csv[0];
unset($csv[0]);
$csvarray = [];
foreach ($csv as $row) {
    $newRow = [];
    foreach ($headers as $k => $key) {
        $newRow[$key] = $row[$k];
    }
    $csvarray[] = $newRow;
}
```

it works fine with any other CSV file, but for this particular CSV it just doesn't work:

example csv:

```
cat,name,des,ldes,datas
1,foo1,desfoo1,<h1>foo</h1><p class="finetext">sometext</p>, data1,data2,data3
3,foo3,desfoo3,<h1>foo3</h1><p class="finetext">sometext</p>, data4,data6
```

the array I got is something like:

```
array (
[cat]=>1
[name]=>foo1
[des]=>desfoo1
[ldes]=>foo
... after this everything breaks...
```

So how can I build an array out this CSV file that has coulmns/values with html...

**UPDATE**

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [cat] => 12
        [name] => Foo no html
        [des] => From foo no html
        [ldes] => 'Basic long desc with htmls
    )
[2] => Array
    (
    [0] =>
    )
[3] => Array
    (
    [0] =>
    basic next row html
    some text inside p with class
    )
```

This is the array I'm getting, it just breaks down to a none sense array...

Comment: I would see two possible problems. Line change is either Windows or Unix-like (one or the other is not managed correctly). Or the encoding is scrapping it all.

Comment: in op array do you want these html tag also ? or only content inside the tag

Comment: @MasterDJon to be honest I have no idea what is happening, I was using excel to build a basic csv file, then I switch to Open Office for more control on how use delimiters, no luck there, then I build a very simple csv manually using single quotes ' to enclose each column same thing no luck...

Comment: In your last snippet what does "everything breaks" exactly mean? What error message or faulty output do you get?

Comment: @aniketashtekar yes all html and any html from the csv is required, also the last column (datas) is bugging me, since the values are separed by commas, but that is not a problem I can fix that but the html....

Comment: i can provide one code , if you run that code through terminal , you will get an array with html tag and content

Comment: @dbrumann is not an error what breaks everything, see my update that is how I got my array it just doesn't make any sense... everything goes fine until the column ldes which is the one with html tags...

Comment: As Master DJon already pointed out, any line breaks _within_ the HTML snippet will break your code as PHP thinks a new CSV line begins.

Comment: @Paul I should have read it more carefully, he is correct, the columns with HTML had carriage return per line and that my friend was the cause of this post. all I had to do was to remove those carriage returns and viola it works!!, thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can accept my comment as an answer, here is the same comment.

> I would see two possible problems. Line change is either Windows or Unix-like (one or the other is not managed correctly). Or the encoding is scrapping it all.

And I would add, line break within a line (like in HTML part).

Answer (score 1):

i think there is no problem with the code, the only problem i found is "you are using `print_r` to output the `$csvarray`, and that is causing issue try not to use `print_r` and if you want better debugger for outputting use kint

https://github.com/kint-php/kint

or use the following modified code

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('docs/foo.csv'));
$headers = $csv[0];
unset($csv[0]);
$csvarray = [];
foreach ($csv as $row) {
    $newRow = [];
    foreach ($headers as $k => $key) {
        $newRow[$key] = htmlentities ($row[$k]);
    }
    $csvarray[] = $newRow;
}

print_r($csvarray);
```